# How many different ways can Riemann-Christoffel Curvature Tensor can be derived?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

In today's Relativity and Gravitation class, my prof was  discussing about Riemann-Christoffel Tensor and he derived it. But in the end he told that there are many ways one can derive the Riemann Tensor. So i wonder how many ways it could be done and wish to learn them.

Comment: How did your professor derive it?

Comment: he did it using covariant derivatives

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160940/how-to-derive-the-riemann-curvature-tensor. There are also several sets of lecture notes that professors have shared online, many with step-by-step derivations. I found several good resources searching "how to derive the Riemann Tensor" on Google.

Comment: My purpose of asking this is this page will serve as a reference for all such derivations.